# Cómo hacer un buscador de frases en cualquier orden

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Estoy realizando una búsqueda con PHP y AJAX. Necesito que no solo me encuentre las coincidencias en el orden original de las frase, si no también que la encuentre en cualquier otro orden.

Me explico: si busco "auto rojo", me encuentra lo que busco sin problema, pero si busco "rojo auto", no encuentra nada.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead style="background-color: #616161;color: #F0F0F0;">
        <tr style="text-align: center;">
            <th style="text-align: center;">Nombre</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta)) {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td  style='text-align: center;'>".$row['nombre']."</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

FUNCION JS

```
$(function(){

$('#bs-prod').on('keyup',function(){
    var dato = $('#bs-prod').val();
    var url = 'busqueda.php';
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:url,
    data:'dato='+dato,
    success: function(datos){
        $('#agrega-registros').html(datos);
    }
});
return false;
});

});
```

BUSQUEDA.PHP

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");


$dato = $_POST['dato'];

//EJECUTAMOS LA CONSULTA DE BUSQUEDA
mysqli_query($conexion,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$registro = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT nombre FROM repuestosfinal WHERE 
nombre LIKE '%$dato%'");
mysqli_query($conexion,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");

//CREAMOS NUESTRA VISTA Y LA DEVOLVEMOS AL AJAX

echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
         <thead style="background-color: #616161;color: #F0F0F0;">
         <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Nombre</th>            
        </tr>
        </thead>';
if(mysqli_num_rows($registro)>0){
mysqli_query($conexion,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
while($registro2 = mysqli_fetch_array($registro)){
    mysqli_query($conexion,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    echo '<tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">'.$registro2['nombre'].'</td>
         </tr>';
}
}else{
echo '<tr>
            <td colspan="6">No se encontraron resultados</td>
      </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

El **LIKE** de Mysql lo que te busca son las coincidencias de caracteres exactamente en el orden en el que le pasas la cadena de texto a buscar. Efectivamente, pasándole "auto rojo" solamente te va a devolver las filas cuyo campo "nombre" contenga la cadena "auto rojo" exacta.

Si lo que necesitas es que te encuentre las filas donde aparezca la cadena, independientemente del orden en el que aparezcan las palabras, deberías hacer una consulta tipo:

**MySQL**

```
SELECT nombre FROM repuestosfinal WHERE nombre LIKE '%auto%' AND nombre LIKE '%rojo%';
```

**AÑADIDO**

Yo lo que haría sería recuperar la cadena que le envías mediante **AJAX** al archivo **busqueda.php** y tras hacerle un `explode()` usando como delimitador el espacio (para separar la cadena en palabras), recorrer el `array` resultante para ir construyendo la **query**.

**PHP**

```
$dato = $_POST['dato'];
$palabras = explode(" ", $dato);

$query = 'SELECT nombre FROM respuestosfinal WHERE ';

foreach ($palabras as $palabra) {
    $query .= "nombre LIKE '%" . $palabra . "%' AND ";
}

//Esta última linea es un truquillo para finalizar el bucle de ANDs 
//concatenados correctamente.
$query .= "nombre LIKE '%%'";


$registro = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
mysqli_query($conexion,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Comment: muchas gracias, funciono de maravilla !